# How sortable attribute of display:column tag works?

Tags: displaytag

I wanted to know how the sortable attribute adds the href of the column header while displaying on the table. when I click on the header table will be sorted. I am bit of newbie to Display tags.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: Okay @RomanC. This question is related to display tag library. display:column is one tag in the library. For this tag there is an attribute of sortable to make the column sorted.Below is the link to see the documentation reference. http://displaytag.sourceforge.net/10/tagreference-displaytag-12.html#column. I wanted to know how sortable creates the header of the column as hyperlink for sorting. any references would help me to deep dive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As displaytag is open source you can browser their source code. And displaytag is nothing more than a bunch of jsp-tags writing html to the output stream.

> How does displaytag create the header of the column as hyperlink for sorting?

The displaytag library puts together their table in the `HtmlTableWriter` class (e.g. [HtmlTableWriter at Github](https://github.com/mmalmeida/displaytag/blob/master/displaytag/src/main/java/org/displaytag/render/HtmlTableWriter.java)). There you can take a look at the `getSortingHref()`-method. This method creates one link with the sorting parameters.

If you use a modern IDE and have the project configured to find the source code of your used libs (e.g. a eclipse maven project) you can most of the time jump into the declaration with `Ctrl+click` on a tag like `<display:column>`.

Comment: Thank you @beendr. I also checked the out the code of didplaytag and walked through the code. I understand now how it creates the hyperlink on the header.